# Loop this nested obj builder function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, build, nested

I have written this clunky function to take two strings and create an object out of them. The goal:

```
// buildObj("house.wall.paint.color", "blue");  
// returns {house: {wall: {paint: {color: "blue"}}}}
```

I am able to do it brute force without a loop, but I'm certain it can be condensed and done much more elegantly with a loop. However, my head explodes in fractal madness as I try to manhandle the nesting and indexing.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/qvkbnv4z/19/)

```
var p1 = "house.wall.paint.color";
var p2 = "blue";
var arr = [];
var obj = [];

buildObj(p1, p2);

console.log(obj);

function buildObj(p1, p2) {
  var keys = p1.split('.');
  var val = p2;
  var arr = $.merge(keys, [val]);
  var prop = {};
  var prop2 = {};
  var prop3 = {};
  var prop4 = {};
  var last = arr.length - 1;
  prop[arr[last - 1]] = arr[last];
  obj = prop;
  prop2[arr[last - 2]] = obj;
  obj = prop2;
  prop3[arr[last - 3]] = obj;
  obj = prop3;
  prop4[arr[last - 4]] = obj;
  obj = prop4;
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop like below

```js
var p1 = "house.wall.paint.color";
var p2 = "blue";
var obj = {};

buildObj(obj, p1, p2);
console.log(obj);


function buildObj(obj, path, value) {
   var keyPath = path.split(".");
   
   var lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length-1;
   for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++ i) {
     key = keyPath[i];
     
     if (!(key in obj)) {
       obj[key] = {}
     }
     obj = obj[key];
     
   }
   obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = value;

}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce right ftw: https://jsfiddle.net/kL6es676/4/

```
function buildObj(keyStr, val) {
  return keyStr.split('.')
    .reduceRight(function(obj, key, i, arr) {
      if (i === arr.length - 1) {
        obj[key] = val
        return obj
      } else {
        var newObj = {}
        newObj[key] = obj
        return newObj
      }
    }, {})
}
```

Comment: This is also spot on... and probably the more concise / better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
function arrayToNestedObj(str, val) {
  const strArray = str.split('.');
  const strLength = strArray.length;
  const obj = {};
  let o = obj;
  for (let i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
    o = o[strArray[i]] = i === strLength - 1 ? val : {}
  }

  return obj;
}
```

with a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qhnsxwjm/

Answer (score 0):

Hi here's my way of doing it:

```
let objStr = "house.wall.paint.color",
    objVal = "Orange",
    newObj = "",
    i = 0;

objStr.replace(new RegExp("\\w+", "g"), (m) => {
    i++;
    newObj += "\{" + "\"" + m + "\"" + "\:";
});
newObj += "\"" + objVal + "\"";
for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) newObj += "}";

console.log(JSON.parse(newObj));
```

It's a fuzzy way, not much strict. I'll keep editing and improving.